# Métodos com mais de um Generic

Tags: c#, .net, genéricos

Existe a possibilidade de criar um método utilizando mais de um tipo de *generic*, mais ou menos assim.

```
    public static TResult ToEntityForType<TResult>(this DataRow row, TType type) where TType : Type
    {
        TResult entity = Activator.CreateInstance<TType>() as TResult;

        List<PropertyInfo> properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();

        DataColumnCollection columnsTable = row.Table.Columns;

        for (int i = 0; i < columnsTable.Count; i++)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = properties.Single(x => x.Name.ToUpper() == columnsTable[i].ColumnName.ToUpper());
            if (prop != null)
            {
                string result = Convert.ToString(row[i]);
                if (result.Trim() == String.Empty)
                    prop.SetValue(entity, null);
                else
                    prop.SetValue(entity, row[i]);
            }
        }
        return entity;
    }
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Passagem de parâmetro Generics em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212901/passagem-de-par%c3%a2metro-generics-em-c)

Comment: @diegofm , um assunto não tem nada a ver com o outro, este apenas estou perguntando se existe a possibilidade de criar métodos com mais de um tipo de Generic, o outro eu pergunto se existe como passar parâmetro Generic sem realmente ter que passar diretamente o nome do Objeto.

Comment: Não está usando mais que um aí, só está usando `TResult`, quer que `TType` seja usado também? Porque? Onde? Esta restrição não faz o menor sentido. Se for pra fazer isso é melhor não usar *generics*.

Comment: @bigown , Fiz a edição do código que tentei realizar aqui, por essa razão precisaria de dois Generics, teria essa possibilidade? é que minha rotina está totalmente generica, e se eu colocar aqui desdo começo o que estou fazendo vai ser muita coisa e quase impossivel de explicar em texto.

Comment: Você criou algum tipo seu herdado de `Type`? Se não criou só precisa de um. Você está tentando usar *generics* onde não cabe. Esse mecanismo não é essa bala de prata toda que está achando que é, e a maioria das coisas que está tentando fazer é mais simples sem ele. Algumas coisas só dá pra fazer sem ele.

Comment: Consegui realizar o que precisa @bigown, utilizei o retorno como object, não queria usar devido o boxing e umboxing, mas não teve jeito. Como faço para posta o código para dizer como resolvi isso?

Comment: Realmente neste caso não caberia utilizar o Generic :/

Comment: @bigown, você conseguiria me ajudar nessa questão? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212851/setar-datasource-em-datagridview-utiizando-heran%C3%A7a-visual-c

Comment: @NicolaBogar mais tarde eu vejo.

Answer (score 2):

Este código funcionará melhor assim:

```
public static TResult ToEntityForType<TResult>(this DataRow row, Type type) {
    var entity = Activator.CreateInstance<type>() as TResult;
    var properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
    foreach (var item in row.Table.Columns) {
        if (properties.Single(x => String.Compare(x.Name, item.ColumnName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0) != null) {
            prop.SetValue(entity, String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(item)) ? null : item));
    }
    return entity;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/Reflection.cs).

Se tivesse um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável  eu mostrava funcionando. Posso ter errado algum detalhe.

Neste caso não precisa de genético em `Type`.

Tem alguns outros detalhes que podem ser feito de forma bem mais simples e mais correta, o código original daria erro em várias situações. Neste não está da melhor forma possível, mas já é uma melhora.

*Generics* é uma forma de polimorfismo. Só deve ser usado se ele é necessário, se realmente pode receber vários tipos diferentes. No caso `Type` só é herdado por um tipo em todo .NET, se você não herdou dele, não tem porque usar *generics*, não há polimorfismo. É só usar o tipo direto.

Colocar `object` no lugar não é solução, é piorar uma situação que começou errada. `object` só funciona assim porque no começo C# não tinha *generics* e era a única forma de generalizar algo. Mas repito, neste caso a generalização nem é necessária.

Como o AP parece estar obcecado por *generics* vou deixar bem claro:

**Só use *generics* onde realmente é necessário, onde traz benefícios**. Estudo o assunto mais profundamente antes de tentar usá-lo. O `TResult` é necessário. Eu só não tenho certeza se pode ser resolvido com ele neste caso.

Tenho até dúvidas se precisa de reflexão mesmo, aí aí precisaria de mais contexto.

Comment: @bigwon, O problema ai de usar o Tresult, quando eu chamado o metodo eu vou precisar chama-lo assim : ToEntityForType<Pais>(Type), mas eu não posso chumbar no meu codigo esse <Pais> entende? por isso não usei o Generic, senão não tenho como especificar o typo desse generic de outra forma sem ser essa.

Comment: Não tem nada disso na pergunta, portanto ela não está clara. Provavelmente tem forma melhor de fazer isto. Eu nem posso ajudar mais porque não tem contexto.

Comment: acabamos chegando no contexto desta pergunta que editei hoje ainda a seu pedido. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212901/passagem-de-par%C3%A2metro-generics-em-c

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi minha questão retornando um Object e usando Type como parâmetro para conseguir criar a instancia do meu objeto.

```
    public static object ToEntityForType(this DataRow row, Type type)
    {
        EntityBase entity = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as EntityBase;

        List<PropertyInfo> properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();

        DataColumnCollection columnsTable = row.Table.Columns;

        for (int i = 0; i < columnsTable.Count; i++)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = properties.Single(x => x.Name.ToUpper() == columnsTable[i].ColumnName.ToUpper());
            if (prop != null)
            {
                string result = Convert.ToString(row[i]);
                if (result.Trim() == String.Empty)
                    prop.SetValue(entity, null);
                else
                    prop.SetValue(entity, row[i]);
            }
        }
        return entity;
    }
```